# Desbordamiento de SqlDateTime. Debe estar entre 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM y 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM

Tags: c#, sql

Buen dia:
estoy utilizando c# con crystal report estoy haciendo un reporte con parametros de fecha , la cuestion cuando ejecuto el procedimiento almacenado en c# me sale el error ya mencionado en el titulo[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] , quisiera saber cual seria mi error.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Como le estas mandando los datos de fecha?

Comment: Aparentemente el sistema está utilizando formato **MM/DD/YYYY** y al recibir una entrada **DD/MM/YYYY** se está desbordando.

Comment: Hola. Puedes indicar cómo rellenas los parámetros del informe vía código C#? Deberías informar un `DateTime` para las fechas en vez de un `String` que seguro es eso.

Comment: Por favor, El código se comparte como texto.

Comment: Trata poniendo set language us_english (con esto pones el formato yyyy-MM-dd) y usa el formato yyyy-MM-dd en tus variables

Answer (score 0):

Mira este ejemplo, dependiendo de que lenguaje tengas en sql cambia el formato de la fecha

```
DECLARE @Fecha DATETIME;

set language us_english
set @Fecha = '2019-01-31' -- yyyy-MM-dd
select @Fecha

set language spanish
set @Fecha = '2019-31-01' -- yyyy-dd-MM
select @Fecha
```

No se con que formato tengas tus variables.